# Progress bar between given time and current time

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I calculate the time between a given time and current time to get the seconds remaining for the progress bar.

It's working, but not when i refresh the page, it starts again from 0%.
I want I like this:

Current time: 15:30:00

Time to given time: 16:00:00

Progress bar is at 50%.

JS:

```
var start = (“01-02-2020 15:00:00”)
var end = (“01-02-2020 16:00:00”
var cur = new Date();

    var diff = end.getTime() - cur.getTime();
    var duration = (diff);

    $outer = $("#pbar_outerdiv");

    $outer.click(function() {
            $('#pbar_innerdiv')
                    .stop()
                    .css({ width: 0 })
                    .animate({ width: "100%" }, duration, "linear", function() { window.location.reload(1); });
    })

    $outer.trigger("click");
                                });

            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="pbar_outerdiv">
        <div id="pbar_innerdiv"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#pbar_outerdiv {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#pbar_innerdiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: I added the code!

Comment: What does `getTime` return, an epoch?  Where do you set the "end time"?

Comment: Then you'll also need a `startTime`, not just the `endTime`. `progress = (now-startTime)/(endTime-startTime);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.  You need to get the starting point, the ending point and the current time.  Find the delta between the end time and the start time to find out the duration of the progress, we'll keep that in `duration`.  Then find how much time has passed since the start time and divide that by `duration`, we'll keep that in `t`.  Then use that as the value of a `<progress/>`.

For the following example, we will set the start time to 15 minutes ago and the end time to 30 minutes from now.

```js
const curr = new Date();
const start = new Date();
const end = new Date();

start.setMinutes(curr.getMinutes() - 15);
end.setMinutes(curr.getMinutes() + 30);

const duration = end.getMinutes() - start.getMinutes();
const t = (curr.getMinutes() - start.getMinutes()) / duration;

console.log(t);

const progress = document.getElementById("progress");
progress.value = t;
```

```html
<progress id="progress" value="0"></progress>
```